# OpenSSL i2d_x509_bio then d2i_x509_bio fails

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I am attempting to implement an SSL client that remembers the cert it received from the server.

When the app comes up it tries to read the previous cert in DER format.

If it didn't find one, it retrieves the cert from the server as an X509 and writes it out in DER format.

Upon subsequent executions, when it reads the cert in the DER format - the d2i_x509_bio fails with a series of errors.

```
bool writeCertificateDER(char * path, X509* newCert)
{
bool rc                     = false;    
BIO *file                   = NULL;
unsigned long error;
char * errorString;

// skipping argument error checking

 if ( NULL == (file = BIO_new_file( path, "w" )) )
    {
        cerr <<  "writeCertificateDER - cannot create file " << path << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if ( i2d_X509_bio( file, newCert ) == 1)
    {
        BIO_flush( file );
        rc = true;
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (error = ERR_get_error( )) != 0 )
        {
            narrowError = ERR_error_string( error, NULL );// uses internal buffer
            RS_CharToWide( errorString, narrowError, tsizeof( errorString ) );
            cerr << "writeCertificateDER - i2d_X509_bio of file ["<< path<< "] failed with error "<<errorString << endl;
        }
        rc = false;
    }

    BIO_free( file );

    return rc;
}

X509 * readCertificateDER( const TCHAR *path )
{
    X509 *newCert= NULL;
    BIO *file = NULL;
    bool rc = false;
    unsigned long error;
    char * errorString;


    if ( path == NULL  || _tcslen(path) == 0)
    {
        cerr << " readCertificateDER - path is NULL." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( NULL == (file = BIO_new(BIO_s_file())) )
        {
            cerr << "readCertificateDER - cannot open file "<< path  << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( BIO_read_filename( file, path ) <= 0 )
            {
                   cerr << "readCertificateDER - cannot read file "<< path << endl;
            }
            else if ( (newCert = d2i_X509_bio( file,NULL )) == NULL )
            {
                while ( (error = ERR_get_error( )) != 0 )
                {
                    errorString = ERR_error_string( error, NULL );// uses internal buffer
                    cerr << "readCertificateDER - d2i of file [" << path << "] failed with error " << errorString );
                }
            }
        }
        BIO_free( file );
    }
    return newCert;
}
```

resulting logs look something like this :

> readCertificateDER - d2i of file [\temp\Cert.der] failed with error error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
>
> readCertificateDER - d2i of file [\temp\Cert.der] failed with error error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:bad object header
>
> readCertificateDER - d2i of file [\temp\Cert.der] failed with error error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error
>
> readCertificateDER - d2i of file [\temp\Cert.der] failed with error error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error
>
> readCertificateDER - d2i of file [\temp\Cert.der] failed with error error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error

I'm fully willing to believe I've omitted one or more step - but would like some help finding out what that or those steps are.

Comment: Hipshot: `IO_new_file( path, "wb" )` - no idea really, but Windows likes binary modes for binary things.

Comment: For this method, it states that the default is binary, unless you use 't' to specify text.  But - worth a shot i guess.